# Jquery mobile footer bar not showing

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

It seems as though my simple php echo statement will not allow me to display footer bars.  When I comment out my php code and view my file the footer bar displays.  When my php is running it does not show my footer.  Any help would be great.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
<title>Mobile</title>
<!-- Include Jquery Mobile dependancies -->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <?php 

$Contents = file_get_contents("http://www.fsb.muohio.edu/directory");
$outer= explode('<div id="c1">',$Contents);
$inner = explode('<div id="c2"', $outer[1]);
$placeholder = array('<table border="0">',"</table>",'<tr>','</tr>','<td>','</td>' );
$replace = array("","","","<br/>","","");
$finished = str_replace($placeholder, $replace, $inner[0]);
echo $finished;
            ?>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a > at the end of the following div tag.   (i.e.  `'<div id="c2">'`)

```
$inner = explode('<div id="c2"', $outer[1]);
```

Also, ensure you're closing those divs and creating a valid HTML document.

Comment: the markup i was getting from the file_get_contents() was invalid.  Thanks